# Search results not showing

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have a problem with my search.php file to render me results...
I dont get any strings of error, but when I type an existing keyword I get no results...
The format of the results are the same as viewed in my main content on the website (grid view)...

The code:

```
<body>
<?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>

<div class='container'> <!--Start of the container-->

<div><?php include("includes/header.php"); ?></div>
<div><?php include("includes/navbar.php"); ?></div>
<div><?php include("includes/left_col.php"); ?></div>
<div class='main_col'>
<div class='main_content'>
<?php
include("includes/connect.php");

if(isset($_GET['search'])){

$search_id = $_GET['q'];

$search_query = "SELECT * FROM games WHERE game_keywords LIKE '%$search_id%'";

$run_query = mysql_query($search_query);

echo '<table>';
$games = 0;
while($search_row = mysql_fetch_array($run_query)){
// make a new row after 9 games
if($games%9 == 0) {
if($games > 0) {
// and close the previous row only if it's not the first
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '<tr>';
}
// make a new column after 3 games
if($games%3 == 0) {
if($games > 0) {
// and only close it if it's not the first game
echo '</td>';
}
echo '<td>';
}

$game_id = $search_row['game_id'];
$game_name = $search_row['game_name'];
$game_category = $search_row['game_name'];
$game_keywords = $search_row['game_name'];
$game_image = $search_row['game_image'];
?>
<div class="game_grid">
<a href="game_page.php?id=<?php echo $game_id; ?>"><img src="images/games_images/<?php echo $game_image; ?>" width="120" height="120" />
<span><?php echo $game_name; ?></span>
</div>
<?php 
$games++;  
}

}
?>
</table>

</div>
</div>
<div><?php include("includes/footer.php"); ?></div>

</div> <!--End of the container-->

</body>
```

Any idea?

EDIT:
I solved my problem, its a small mistake I made,
In the HTML form of the search I forgot to give the submit button: "name="search", I removed it accidently... now everything works perfectly :)

Comment: mysql_query($search_query); start using mysqli_query,mysql is deprecated.

Comment: Did you try execute the same query directly in the database (using for example phpMyAdmin or console)? Are you getting correct results this way?

Comment: dint get ur code my friend please make it proper. if possible make it live on some fiddle if available and stop using mysql_* functions it is depericated in PHP 5.5

Comment: The search worked perfectly until I set the results to show on grid view, same as the index.php page, so after I changed the "main_content" in the search.php I stopped to get results...

Comment: When the website will be finished I will convert everything to MySQLi ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in code
change code as below

```
if(isset($_GET['search'])){    
   $search_id = $_GET['search']; //$_GET['q'];
.
.
.    
}
```

Comment: its not that, it was value before I turned it into "q", I didnt forgot to change the HTML search form from "value" to "q" aswell...

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, its a small mistake I made, In the HTML form of the search I forgot to give the submit button: "name="search", I removed it accidentally... now everything works perfectly :)